# Can I shoot through Deathtrap?

Tags: borderlands-2

Due to Deathtrap's love of melee attacks and extreme speed, he very often blocks one or more targets from my sight. Can I shoot through him and damage enemies? I tried a few times and while I confirmed I'm not hurting Deathtrap I couldn't tell if my bullets can actually go through his model or not.

Comment: My guess would be that no, you cannot, given that one of Gaige's skills allows her to "charge up" Deathtrap by shooting it with elemental guns. However, this is just a guess and I don't have physical evidence to back this up. Would love an actual answer to this as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bullets do not go through Deathtrap. However, rockets and other things that explode on contact (glob gun shots for example) *do* go through deathtrap.

How I tested it:

1. I cleared an area of enemies and summoned Deathtrap.
2. I then positioned him between myself and a corrosion barrel.  Close enough that even if I missed him due to Anarchy I couldn't hit the barrel.
3. I then unloaded several clips into him, aiming at the barrel on the other side of him.
4. The barrel didn't go off.
5. To double check that I wasn't mistaken in my aim; I waited for him to disappear and then shot once, blowing up the barrel.

Additionally, to try to rule out ricochets off of Deathtrap I performed another test:

1. I have 5 points in Close Enough (50% chance to ricochet)
2. I summoned DeathTrap and positioned him in front of me, with the barrel off to my side.
3. I unloaded several clips into him, aiming at different points and strafing to ensure that if I was ricocheting that it shouldn't have been able to miss.

I noticed that no ricochet trails were appearing on screen, and the barrel did not explode.

Comment: Were you specced into Close Enough during the test? If so, that would conclusively rule out DT as being a ricochet-able surface as well, as Close Enough bullets *will* strike and destroy barrels. Edit: If not, I'd re-run the test and fire at a 90 degree angle to the barrel with Deathtrap as the "corner", so to speak.

Comment: I am specced in Close Enough; I'll modify my answer to rule out ricochets.

Comment: Good stuff with the re-resting for the ability to ricochet off of DT! :) Consider the upvote fully earned.

Answer (score 3):

In regards to it being a moving object like any other NPC. I recently was in fight for your life mode as Zero, and between Deathtrap and I was a grouping of baddies to be shooting at. I had the bore spec, so thought nothing of shooting through deathtrap, but no bullets went through, and damaged the ones behind deathtrap. Thus I died, and well yeah, bullets don't go through Deathtrap, no matter the circumstances.

Comment: Interesting that even Bore doesn't go through him

Answer (score 0):

I think since it's a moving object like any other NPC in the game,the bullet won't go through until it's dead. It's like when you kill a monster and another is right behind it. If the one in front is dead, you'll be able to shoot through it to reach the one behind.

So since DT is considered an alive object, you can't shoot through it :(