# How can I build Deathtrap to make him the least annoying in team play?

Tags: borderlands-2

Deathtrap can be annoying; [he blocks shots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87348/can-i-shoot-through-deathtrap), he can't be recalled and he has a tendency to go for melee attacks, drawing targets' aggro. This is particularly annoying in team play as I've noticed he'll either steal kills or aggro away enemies coop partners could use for Second Winds. It's also hard to shoot a target when you're down, your accuracy is low, and Deathtrap is right there between you and the target.

Which skills (if any) can I use to make deathtrap more of a "team player" or at least draw less aggro? I've noticed for example One Two Boom doesn't appear to draw aggression. Do long-range skills of his draw less/no aggro? His distance attacks certainly seem less in-the-way, so I assume that's a big part of it.

Comment: I also find it bitterly ironic the "best buddy" character has the action skill that's the most annoying in team play. Deathtrap is really better for *solo*

Comment: Not worth a full answer, but this might be an issue of having a lot of close-range fighters. I'm usually running Maya with a Sniper Rifle, and my buddy's Deathtrap is *wonderful* for drawing attention so I can concentrate on those crits.

Answer (score 5):

Deathtrap is a situation based skill to use. And while the situation comes up quite often in single player, it does not come up that often in co-op play. My overall suggestion is to use Deathtrap less if you find he is in the way that often. You may feel this lessens the effectiveness of your character, but there again so does having 3 other people there to help you out!

I have not seen any Deathtrap skills change his AI pattern to this point yet, but I have not used the heal-shields ability so that may alter it a bit. He will always pick a target (And most often its the most moronic of them all) and then go up and attack it with a melee or ranged attack depending on if the target is land or air based.

That being said there are pretty much two situations that I will release him in (Again, only in co-op I use him All the time when solo due to using the mechromancer's anarchy build).

- **To knock down the annoying flying targets**. Deathtrap always has his ranged and melee ranged skills from level 5 onward. Since his ranged attacks always hit he is very handy to take down the drones and such that can fly overhead while you and your team focus on the ground targets.
- **Ambush situations**. As you mention he is good at gaining agro and this helps in these situations. When you are in a location and open up a chest, complete an objective or whatever that suddenly puts 6+ red dots around you, pop off Deathtrap and he will occupy 1-3 of them depending on how his AI goes.

The overall goal is to use Deathtrap only in situations where you need to control the AI's targeting of yourself and the people you are playing in co-op (or to get rid of an annoying target that is not worth your bullets). Using him in a situation when people are dropping you have to go in with the understanding you are going to be bringing people back up and they are not likely to get second winds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: His laser and shock-ball are sort of "ranged" but will be used against normal targets, not just stuff he can't otherwise reach. I also subjectively noticed he seems more aggressive with the Ordered Chaos tree 7 slash attack skill, so I stopped using that. So I think his behavior changes a bit, but food points otherwise.

Comment: @BenBrocka Oh, Deathtrap can fly on his own and I have seen him go through walls to get things (was Extremely obvious in the caustic caves last night) to reach opponents so whether or not he can 'get' to them or not does not really come into play. I have also seen what you have seen, I was just attempting to give more general information as to what he will Usually do.

Comment: By "get to" I really mean flying enemies like rakk/surveyors. Those are almost all he uses the blue lightening bolt on